# Make playlists either public or private from user side

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, rdbms

I have two tables `playlists` and `playlist_songs` in database.Recently playlist is managed by authority, but now i want to allow user to make their own playlists and the playlist can either be `public` or be `private` depending on user's choice. So, how can I design schema for that, and how can i make `public-playlists` visible to other users, and how to hide `private-playlists` from other user? please suggest me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is too general.And also you should design your tables base on your requirement.we may not know your requirement like you.

Comment: may be my question is too general, but i am new to laravel, and i don't have idea that how can i make public playlists to be visible to other user's and private to be hidden for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding flag field `is_public` in your table `playlists`

so add field `is_public` as `char(1)` in your database table `playlists`

And While storing playlist just add data as `Y` or `N` in your table as per users selection.

```
$store_array = [
    // other fields
    'is_public' => 'Y',
];
```

And by default you can set is_public `Y` for public and `N` for private. You can set it in your database while creating field.

And to display you can make condition like below in your code where you are showing playlists( in grid or anywhere i don't know where you are displaying playlists)

Wherever you are getting playlists to show it to users use eloquent like below to make sure other users can view only public playlists

```
$playlists = Playlist::get()->where('is_public','=','Y');
```

So by using this eloquent you will get only playlists that are chosen to be public.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am going to implement as per suggestion, but in logic part of `if-else` condition how can i make it available publicly? please describe it.

Comment: check my updated answer. you will need to make modifications in your code as per your requirement. as i dont know your code i cant provide specific solution. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Great ! If it really helped you than please close this question by accepting my answer. Thank you!